# Drupal: sync users accounts between 2 different Drupal websites

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, synchronization

I've a Drupal A website with users accounts running on server A and with domain A.

Now, I need to build a Drupal B website on server B and domain B, and when someone register on Drupal B, he is automatically registered on Drupal A.

In other terms, I need so sync the users accounts.
Can i easily make it ?

thanks

Comment: Note that Bakery does not sync roles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to write something to export the users from Site A.  Then use [Feeds](http://drupal.org/project/feeds) to import.  You may be able to use [Rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules) or some custom scripts to export from Site A to go into Site B (probably by running drupal cron on both in sequence).

Another idea would be to use the same database table for both.  This is accomplished easily.

For Site B's settings file:

```
$db_prefix = array(
  'users' => 'siteAdb.',
);
```

where siteAdb is the database that contains Site A's drupal installation so long as both databases use the same account.  Of course you would have to apply any appropriate prefixes.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at the following projects/documentation:

- http://drupal.org/project/bakery with documentation at http://drupal.org/node/567410 for single sign-on on sites on the same domain (example.com, subsite.example.com, subsite2.example.com)
- http://drupal.org/node/22267 sharing database tables across Drupal sites, which is what Andrew was going for
- http://drupal.org/project/domain splits up a single "site" into domains
- http://drupal.org/project/sso Single Sign-On
- [Is it possible to share users between a Drupal 6.x and Open Atrium database, based on organic groups or CiviCRM smart groups?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2296548/is-it-possible-to-share-users-between-a-drupal-6-x-and-open-atrium-database-base) similar question on Stack Overflow